# SwiftUI: using MatchedGeometryEffect for a scrollView?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to understand `MatchGeometryEffect` a little better.  I am trying to put it on each cell of a list in a scrollView.  I want it to be where if `showAlternate` is `false`, the main cell is show but if `showAlternate` is `true` , then the individual cell will show the `else` of the conditional which would be a larger cell ( not part of the code yet).  I have the `matchedGeometryEffect` on the `ForEach` right now but how can I do each cell indvidually?

```
 struct ContentView: View {
        @Binding var countries: [Country]
        @State var showAlternate = false;
        @Namespace var namespace;
      


    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(Array(countries.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index,country) in
                    LazyVStack {
                        HStack {
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination: CountryView(country: country),
                                label: {
                                    HStack {
                                        Image(country.image)
                                            .resizable()
                                            .scaledToFit()
                                        Text(country.display_name)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                            .padding(.leading)
                                        Spacer()
                                    }
                                    .padding(.top, 12.0)
                                    .frame(height: 80)
                                }
                            ).buttonStyle(FlatLinkStyle())                                   
                        }                            
                        .padding(.horizontal, 16.0)
                        .overlay(Divider(), alignment: .top)                            
                    }
                }
                .background(Rectangle().opacity(0.2).matchedGeometryEffect(id: "shape", in: namespace))
            }
        }
        .font(Font.custom("Avenir", size: 22))
    }
}
```

Comment: This should help https://swiftui-lab.com/matchedgeometryeffect-part1/

Comment: @Asperi this is great, thank you!